# ошибка запуска скомпилированного (tkinter, pyinstaller) кода python

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Написал программу в Tkinter, скомпилировал, на своем компьютере все работает. Если перенести на компьютер, где нет Питона выводит ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ATB.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _tkinter: Параметр задан неверно.
```

Думал что неправильно написал где-то, и закомментировал весь код, импорты... и оставил только Label с надписью HelloWorld, проблема не исчезает

компиляция через pyinstaller, скрипт использует tkinter

```
__author__ = 'Gapbarov Eziz'
__version__ = 'Graphical 3.0'

# from tkinter import messagebox
# from Stansion import *
# from tkinter import *
# from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Label

app_win = Tk()
app_win.geometry('400x300+400+200')
app_win.title('ATB')
app_win.resizable(False, False)
app_win.iconphoto(False, PhotoImage(file='phone.png'))

label = Label(app_win, background='white', relief=RIDGE, width=34, text='Hello World !') 
label.place(x=50, y=50)

app_win.mainloop()
```

Прочитал статьи на StackOverFlow, воспользовался коммандами

```
pip install tk

pip install pytk

pyinstaller ATB.py --exclude-module tkinter -F -w -i=atb.ico

pyinstaller -F -w -i=atb.ico --add-data "C:/py/DLLs/tcl86t.dll;." --add-data "C:/py/DLLs/tk86t.dll;." --add-data "C:/py/Lib/tkinter;tkinter/"  ATB.py
```

Когда зарускаю на другом компютере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: os Windows7 x64, python 3.8 x64,  попробовал скомпилировать и на Windows 7 x86 с Python 3.8 x86 результат не меняется, прочитал еще советы, что может быть из за двух версий python на одной операционной системе, удалил вторую, не помогает!

Comment: удалил python 3.8 x32  и установил его на Virtual box, оставил только python 3.8 x64

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему для x64 разрадный Windows 7 - переустановкой python  версии 3.8. Для x32 разрядного Windows 7 установкой python версии 3.7